# docker network - assign multiple ip-range by itables

Tags: docker, squid

I need add to my docker network which I using for squid, outgoing ip range from xx.ip to yy.ip.
At the moment I adding single ip using bellow command:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.0/16 ! -o bridge-coi -j SNAT --to-source 1xx.xxx.xxx.xx4
```

How I can add range ip?

When I put several many above command, not working.